# Adding Columns in 2D array (Python)

Tags: python, arrays, list

So I am trying to add all the columns of a 2D array except for the first two columns of the array. If the sum of the row is greater than or equal to 9 and less than 12, I want the function to print the row. Here is a sample of my 2D array that is a list of lists:

```
[[12606.000,  74204.000,     1.000,     1.000,     1.000,     1.000,     1.000,     0.000,     0.000],        
[12606.000,  105492.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     1.000],    
[12606.000,  112151.000,     1.000,     1.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000],     
[12606.000,  121896.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     1.000,     0.000]]
```

(Some columns were deleted for formatting).
Here is my code:

```
def sumBinRow(A):
    """Returns the list of employees recording data for at least nine months and fewer than twelve.
    """
    for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(A[i])):
            if 9 <= sum(A[i][j+2]) <12:
                print A[i]
```

I keep getting a "Type Error" saying the 'int' object is not iterable.

Comment: Sort of. It's a project for my internship

Comment: I get the same error when I try: "for j in range(12)" as well

Comment: Sorry... Wrong thread

Comment: So you call your function with the argument being the list of lists above?

Comment: Yes A is the list of lists that is the input of the function

Comment: You are not using the sum the right way...

Comment: Ahhh, I see. You call `sum(A[i][j+2])`. `sum` consumes an iterable not a number.

Comment: @user3758443 did you check the answer below using NumPy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you need to iterate over each list, for each list, take a slice of that list starting from 2, then sum that and do your comparison.

```
def sumBinRow(A):
    """Prints the list of employees recording data for at least nine months and fewer than twelve.
    """
    for row in A:
        if 9 <= sum(row[2:]) < 12:
            print row
```

or in 1 line cause why not :P

```
def sumBinRow(A):
    """Prints the list of employees recording data for at least nine months and fewer than twelve.
    """
    print [row for row in A if 9 <= sum(row[2:]) < 12]
```

Comment: Was going to suggest just the same thing. Although I'd adapt the name and the docstring to what the function actually does...

Answer (score 0):

You should should sum like this.

```
def sumBinRow(A):
    """Returns the list of employees recording data for at least nine months and fewer than twelve.
    """
    for i in range(len(A)):
        sigma = 0
        for j in range(2,len(A[i])):
            sigma += A[i][j]
            if 9 <= sigma <12:
                print A[i]
```

Comment: I understand your solution and really like it but for some reason the function is returning rows that have all 1's

Comment: [12227.0, 38606.0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[12227.0, 38606.0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[12227.0, 67307.0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
[12227.0, 67307.0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

Answer (score 0):

If you use `NumPy` for this task it would be simpler and much faster:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[12606.000,  74204.000,     1.000,     1.000,     1.000,     1.000,     1.000,     0.000,     0.000],
              [12606.000,  105492.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     1.000],
              [12606.000,  112151.000,     1.000,     1.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000],
              [12606.000,  121896.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     0.000,     1.000,     0.000]])

b = a[:, 2:].sum(axis=1)
check = (b >= 9) & (b < 12)
print(a[check])
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are trying to sum over something that is not an array:

```
if 9 <= sum(A[i][j+2]) <12: // A[j][j+2] is not iterable, it is an int
```

Instead you want to use the [**slice**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) function:

```
if 9 <= sum(A[i][2:]) <12:  // This will sum sum all but first two elements
```

A more pythonic way would be to use a [**list comprehension**](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions). This can be done with a single line of code:

```
A = [[12606, 74204 , 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0],        
     [12606, 105492, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],    
     [12606, 112151, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],     
     [12606, 121896, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]

print [row for row in A if 9 <= sum(row[2:]) < 12]
```